# loading jQuery js file at the bottom of page and using usercontrols with javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-controls

what is the best method to using js files (like jquery.js) at the bottom of page and using usercontrols with javascripts (included js files and inline codes) that used in deferent places of page.

in additional information we have a lot of usercontrols with dedicated js files and inline javascripts that used like a package in deferent pages in deferent places and we want to manage this scripts and move that all down in the rendered page with the best method and clean coding.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how to move javascripts used in usercontrols to the bottom of rendered page?